# How to monitor a serial connection @ 250000 baud?

Tags: cat, serial-port, stty

I wish to directly monitor the serial-over-usb connection to my 3d printer, which runs at 250000 baud.  e.g I might monitor it with `cat /dev/ttyUSB0`

However first I need to set the baud rate, e.g `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200`

But if I try and set the baud rate to 250k, it fails:

`stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 250000`

gives result:

`stty: invalid argument 250000`

It appears that baud rate 250000 is not supported under Ubuntu/Mint.  Can anyone suggest an alternative way to monitor this serial connection?

Comment: Try `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 250000`, but afaik, you can only stablish one serial connection, so it's monitorization or 3d printer

Comment: 250000 is a non-standard bitrate, but `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 500000` works. I couldn't get 250000 with `stty`, `screen`, `setserial`, `python`, or whatever else I tried. I eventually gave up, recompiled and set bitrate to 500000 in 3D printer firmware. It turned out to be easy. I get faster transfers. And the `Configuration.h` header file comment said it could even speed up the 3D printer's sd-card access.

Comment: That's a great tip thanks.  Just curious if you tried the below `mysetbaud.py`? It should allow you to set the baud rate to `stty...250000`. (not that you need to any more)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some undocumented ioctls you can use to set non-standard speeds, provided the driver implements them. A simple way to call them is with a small piece of python. Eg put in file `mysetbaud.py` and `chmod +x` it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# set nonstandard baudrate. http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/327366/119298
import sys,array,fcntl

# from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py
# /usr/include/asm-generic/termbits.h for struct termios2
#  [2]c_cflag [9]c_ispeed [10]c_ospeed
def set_special_baudrate(fd, baudrate):
    TCGETS2 = 0x802C542A
    TCSETS2 = 0x402C542B
    BOTHER = 0o010000
    CBAUD = 0o010017
    buf = array.array('i', [0] * 64) # is 44 really
    fcntl.ioctl(fd, TCGETS2, buf)
    buf[2] &= ~CBAUD
    buf[2] |= BOTHER
    buf[9] = buf[10] = baudrate
    assert(fcntl.ioctl(fd, TCSETS2, buf)==0)
    fcntl.ioctl(fd, TCGETS2, buf)
    if buf[9]!=baudrate or buf[10]!=baudrate:
        print("failed. speed is %d %d" % (buf[9],buf[10]))
        sys.exit(1)

set_special_baudrate(0, int(sys.argv[1]))
```

This takes some code from the `pyserial` package with constants for the various values needed from Linux C include files, and an array for the `struct termios2`. You use it with a baud rate parameter and your device on stdin, eg from bash:

```
./mysetbaud.py <>/dev/ttyUSB0 250000
```

Comment: Thankyou that worked perfectly! Amazing. I can now directly send Gcode to the printer, example: `echo "M115" >> /dev/ttyUSB0` while monitoring the status in another terminal with just `tail -f /dev/ttyUSB0`

Answer (score 4):

```
setserial -a /dev/ttyUSB0 spd_cust
setserial -a /dev/ttyUSB0 divisor 96
```

Now set the port to 38400 to get 250000

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 38400
```

(or use it as 38400 in an application, e.g. ser2net)

Got my info from http://www.linurs.org/linux/SerialPort.html

Comment: This worked great for connecting to my 3D printer.  I used the first two commands and then "screen /dev/ttyUSB0 38400".  I can type to the printer and receive output, too.

Comment: Would append that `setserial -a /dev/ttyUSB0` displays `Baud_base` by which you can determine the divisor value to use.

Comment: Why 96? 250000 / 38400 = 6.51. Can you elaborate?

Comment: First you use `setserial -a /dev/ttyUSB0` to get Baud_base. Here e.g. 24000000. Then divisor needs to be 96 to get to 250000. Subsequently `setserial /dev/ttyUSB0 divisor 96 spd_cust` makes it such that when using 38400 a custom speed is selected.